# Worklight busyindicator not working on Blackberry Devices

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

In the main js file we have initialized the WL busyindicator in WLCommoninit method and are invoking the busy.show in respective adapter js methods, please find the code snippet below

```
var busy; 
function wlCommonInit() {     
   busy = new WL.BusyIndicator('content', {
          text : 'Please Wait...'
   });
};
```

Calling busy indicator in other js files as
    busy.show();

the above methodology is working fine for Android and IOS but not blackberry. Could you please let me know how to fix this

Comment: what is your Worklight version?

Comment: worklight version is 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The following will work (verified by previewing via Worklight Console).
Tested [with Worklight 6.1.0.**1**](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=worklight%206.1.0.1&oq=worklight%206.1.0.1&aqs=chrome..69i57.2702j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8).

Note using `null` instead of `content`.

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    busy = new WL.BusyIndicator(null, { text: "Please wait..." });
}
```

As for using it... from reading the question, it sounds like you are calling it INSIDE the adapter code? You should call `busy.show()` *before* you invoke the adapter procedure and call `busy.hide()` *after* you're done processing the adapter response.

Comment: hi Idan, thanks for the reply. yes am using busy.show() before invoking the adapter procedure and busy.hide() at the end. FYI this works fine for iphone, Android.

Comment: Try as the answer suggests, with "null" instead of content. Also mention how you are testing this. Which BB OS. What about in the Worklight Console MBS? Please answer all questions.

Comment: It works fine in MBS, but on physical devices BB OS 10.0, BB 6.0, 7.1  its not working.

Comment: Try only the above code snippet in a new app with the bb envs (not in your app), see if it fails still.

Comment: I have uploaded the sample app where we tried the below 

We have called busyIndicatorDemo()(OIDHandler.js) function on  following button clicks
 
1)Login (CommonUIControlsApp.html)
 
2)ForgottenPassword (CommonUIControlsApp.html)
 
3)Next (CommonUIControlsApp.html# Registration)
 
Observation : Busy indicator is loading behind the page background…
you can find the sample app @ https://www.dropbox.com/s/dx2xclc79aoi27h/CommonUIControlsApp.zip  
Expected behavior : Busy indicator must load on page and it must cover entire page until operation is  done on page.

Comment: @Shireesh, WHICH BlackBerry OS does not display a busy indicator? 6? 7? 10? Preview?

Comment: We have tested it on BB10 device, the busy indicator in fact goes into the background

Comment: What is your Worklight version?

Comment: This project in the .zip is a mess; please upload a project that contains ONLY the problem. Only, the problem.